# Dataset for testing KeyDB

Tags: redis, in-memory-database, keydb

I'm new to the world of in-memory dbs, expecially the KeyDb is known to me for just like a couple of days, I wonder if the dataset that KeyDb/Redis had been tested on, is publicly available. I would like to do testing myself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's seeking an off site resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use benchmarking software to generate different loads for KeyDB or Redis. KeyDB has a built in benchmarking software 'keydb-benchmark', or 'redis-benchmark' for redis. However the best benchmarking tools are [Memtier](https://github.com/RedisLabs/memtier_benchmark) by RedisLabs which is great for testing throughput, and [YCSB](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/) by Yahoo which is great for testing latency under different loads. YCSB has several predefined workloads you can use and test on many different databases for a comparison. Each tool has pretty good documentation on using it.

You can take a look here at some [redis benchmark](https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks) examples. Also see this section of keydb blog outlining considerations for avoiding bottlenecks while [benchmarking keydb with memtier](https://docs.keydb.dev/blog/2020/03/02/blog-post/#reproducing-benchmarks). Both documents include some different examples/commands.